# How can i make grid 9x9 with no duplicate rows ? (example)

Tags: c#, matrix, grid, nested-loops

i tried to make grid 9x9 with no duplicate rows number like this

```
   4 6 1 | 9 5 3 | 8 2 7
   5 6 8 | 3 1 2 | 7 4 9
   1 8 9 | 3 6 4 | 2 5 7
   ---------------------
   4 9 6 | 2 1 3 | 5 8 7
   6 4 5 | 9 1 3 | 8 2 7
   7 4 8 | 6 9 3 | 2 5 1
   ---------------------
   7 8 5 | 2 1 4 | 3 9 6
   7 5 2 | 4 8 9 | 3 6 1
   7 9 1 | 8 4 2 | 5 3 6
```

dont worry about ---- and | | |

what i did is :

```
 int[,] y = new int[9, 9];
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < y.GetLength(0); i++)
            {

                for (int j = i-1; j < y.GetLength(0); j++)
                {

                    //int s = rnd.Next(1, 10);

                    if (j != i )
                    {
                        y[i, j] = j;
                        count++;
                    }

                    for (int k = count; k < j; k++)
                    {
                        y[i, j] = j - i;
                        Console.Write(" " + y[i, j]);
                    }
                    Console.Write(" " + y[i, j]);



                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```

it give me

```
0 0 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

1 0 3 4 5 6 7 8
 2 0 4 5 6 7 8
 3 0 5 6 7 8
 4 0 6 7 8
 5 0 7 8
 6 0 8
 7 0

Comment: I updated my answer, with a better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

So what you need is reading about sudoku algorithm with rollback.  Mostly what you need to do is:

> Create an method that would check each row and each column and each
>   box(3x3) to make sure there is no duplication(1 to 9)

You need to find out which number can be put in an empty square and choose one randomly.  If you have no choice, you need to rollback a few step back and start again, or simply clear the whole grid.

I [wrote](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33894/Creating-a-Sudoku-game) this article a long time ago.

Comment: it's hard to understand sudoku :(

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention anything in the requirement that the rows have to be random, just that they cannot be duplicated;

How about pushing the last number of each row to be the first number in the next row.

So you can make a list or array
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

First row of matrix is the array in current order.

Next iteration, take the 9 and insert at beginning, and your second matrix row will look like:

9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

Do this 9 times and you will end up with no duplicate rows. This is based on round robin algorithm, which is slightly more complex but used to schedule sports games so teams never play the same team twice before the have played all teams in the league.

Can you build the c# from this explanation?

Comment: Unfortunately this will have duplicates within 3x3 spaces in the matrix - perhaps a but too simple :)